Sup norm can always be made smaller without altering the value of the Riemann-integral
Set $\alpha>0$ and let $V := \{f\in C^0([0,1]) : f(0) = 0\}$ be equipped with the sup norm $\Vert\cdot \Vert_\infty$. I'm trying to show that for every $f\in V$ with $\int_{0}^{1} f(x) \, dx = \alpha$ there is $g\in V$ such that $\int_{0}^{1} g(x) \, dx = \alpha$ and $\Vert g\Vert_\infty < \Vert f\Vert_\infty$. Intuitively I feel that this should be achievable because one must "make $f$ smaller" at the points where it reaches its maximum and "make $f$ larger" at certain places where it does not reach its maximum to compensate for the value of the integral. However, I don't really have a clear and formal idea of ​​how one can do this.

Hint (I haven't followed through). Without the condition that the function vanish at $0$ you could think about the constant function with value $\alpha$. Can you modify that function to keep it continuous, vanish at $0$ and not change by too much elsewhere?

@EthanBolker Great! (since with the obvious necessary condition $|f|\infty>0$, we have $|\alpha|<|f|\infty$). Why don't you post an answer?

@AnneBauval Done. Let's see what the OP does with it.

I think I got it, thank you both.

@AnneBauval can this also be done via approximations of functions in $C^0([0,1])$?

Sorry @homosapien, I don't know.

A slightly different version of the hint is that if $f(0)=0$ and $f$ is continuous, then $\int_0^1 f < | f |_\infty$.

@AlexanderPruss It is not a different version. It is a complement, tacit in the hint but explicited in my comment: $|\alpha|<|f|_\infty$.  Don't forget the $|~|$.

Hint: Without the condition that the function vanish at 0
you could think about the constant function with value $\alpha$.
Can you modify that function to keep it continuous, vanish at 0
and not change by too much elsewhere?
